# How do I get table Data from a row onChange of dropdown menu when an event is fired in React?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, event-handling

**Here's the workflow:**

1. User accesses my react component that renders a table
2. One of the  elements within each row has a dropdown menu
3. User changes the value of the dropdown (flavor)
4. An event is fired that submits this data to our APIService

**Here's the problem:**

When I consume the drop down change event that's fired after selection, it contains the new flavor. However, it doesn't tell me the record from the table that changed (which I need). I need this to update the record in the backend.

**Here's the code:**

```
...
<tbody>
   {data.map((row, key) => (
       <tr key={key}
           <td>
               <select onChange={handleStatusChange} className="form-select">
               <option value="value">{myObject[key].flavor}</option>
               <option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
               <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
               <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
           </td>
 ...
```

The weird thing is that I can obviously identify row and row id from "row/key" within the table. However, whenever I consume the event, none of that data is there:

```
const handleStatusChange = (event, id:any) => {

    backendService.setNewFlavor(data).then(response) => {
      ...this needs row.flavorID
 
    }
}
```

**What I've tried**

- Manually getting the row index with *event.target.parentElement.rowIndex* and seeing if I can do anything with that, but it says that's undefined (and idk if I'd be able to do anything with it anyway).
- Looking at examples in other applications (most seem to use MUI to handle event listeners).
- Trying to invoke the data element passed into the component (it just says it's null). That component looks like this:

  ```
   const IceCreamTable = ( {data} ) => {

   const handleStatusChange = (event, id:any) => {...}

   return (
    ...table from previous code snippet
   )

  }
  ```

I don't need you to spoonfeed me or solve the problem for me, I just need an example of someone doing something like this.

Bonus points if we can make this change dynamically render to the page without refreshing it.

Comment: Is `key` sufficient to identify the record?  Usually data would (should) include some unique identifier, the index in the array can be pretty arbitrary in many situations.  (e.g. if the data is ever sorted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `key` (which is just the array index) really is the "unique identifier" you need then you can simply pass it to the handler function:

```
onChange={e => handleStatusChange(e, key)}
```

Then the function signature you have would receive those two arguments:

```
const handleStatusChange = (event, id:any) => {
```

---

Alternatively, if *`row` itself* contains an identifier you can use, you can pass that to the handler:

```
onChange={e => handleStatusChange(e, row.id)}
```

Or pass the entire `row` itself:

```
onChange={e => handleStatusChange(e, row)}
```

Basically, you can pass whatever argument(s) you like to `handleStatusChange`.